# If $U \times V$ is in the natural basis of $T^2$, why are $U,V$ open in $T$?

Tags: general-topology

I have a question about the "if" direction of [Proof Wiki's proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorff_Space_iff_Diagonal_Set_on_Product_is_Closed) that a a topological space $T = (S , \tau )$ is a Hausdorff space iff the diagonal set $\Delta_s = \{ ( x,x ) : x \in S \}$ is closed in $T^2 = ( S \times S , \mathcal{T} )$.

> Now suppose $\Delta_S$ is closed in $T^2 = \left({S \times S, \mathcal T}\right)$.
>
> Then $H = \left\{{\left({x, y}\right) \in S \times S: x \ne y}\right\}$ is open in $T^2$.
>
> Let $\left({x, y}\right) \in H$.
>
> We have that $x \ne y$ by the nature of $H$.
>
> Then there exists an element $U \times V$ in the natural basis of $T^2$, and therefore open in $T^2$.
>
> As $U \times V \subseteq H$ it follows that $U \cap V = \varnothing$.
>
> By definition of the product topology, as $U \times V$ is open in $T^2$, then $U$ and $V$ are both open in $T$.
>
> So, for any $\left({x, y}\right)$ we have $U, V \subseteq S$ such that $x \in U, y \in V, U \cap V = \varnothing$.
>
> So $T$ is a $T_2$ (Hausdorff) space.
>
> $\blacksquare$

Can someone explain the three lines before the QED $\blacksquare$ here? I understand everything prior.

I don't understand. We take an arbitrary element of $(S\times S)\setminus \triangle_S$ which is fine, and then we use the Hausdorff property to show that $x$ and $y$ are in disjoint neighborhoods in $X$. Show these neighborhoods are both in $H$, and then we know $H$ is open? Since any arbitrary points have neighborhoods in $H$, $H$ is open is that right?

Comment: $U\times V$ is a product of open sets, thus by definition, it's an element of the basis for the product topology.

Comment: Tychonoff topology is the product topology. In the case that the product is finite, it is simple to understand it: a basis of open sets is formed by products of open sets.

Comment: @StefanHamcke See clarification on my continued lack of understanding

Comment: It's because you took an arbitrary point $(x,y)\in H$ and showed that there is an open set which contains that pair and is contained in $H$. That means $H$ is a neighborhood of each of its points, hence it is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have a finite product space $$X=\prod_{i\in I} X_i,$$
we define the basis for the topology of $X$ to be $$\mathcal{B}=\{U_1\times\cdots\times U_n: U_i\subset X_i\text{ is open}\}.$$

In the case that this is an infinite direct product of topological spaces, we need to require that only finitely many of the open sets can be non-proper, meaning that the basis is given by:
$$\mathcal{B} = \left\{\prod_i U_i: U_{j_1},\cdots,U_{j_n},\quad U_{j_q}\subset X_{j_q},\quad \forall i\ne j_1,\cdots,j_n,\quad U_i=X_i \right\}$$

---

In our case, we see that $U\times V$ is open in $T^2$ and hence by the definition of the product topology, we have that $U,V$ are both open in $T$.